What is the board called on the bottom edge of the exterior of my house under the siding?
I just bought a home. The previous owner let a gutter leak get out of control and consistent drip and splash in one spot on the concrete around the house decayed the bottom edge of the siding and the board underneath has rotted. I’ve looked under the underlayment and it seems to be only this bottom board.
I’m having a hard time researching a fix because I don’t know the right names for this area. I’ve seen a variety of names but not sure if any are correct. Anyone who can tell me what to google would be appreciated.
The house was built in 1904 but has many updates. The siding is fiber cement (some probably asbestos, some seem to be newer non-asbestos fiber cement). The board in question is not a sheet of plywood but a wood board probably 1” thick and six inches high. Above it as far as I can see id another separate board. If it helps I’m in the Colorado front range.
Also, if anyone is knowledgeable is this wood structural at all? Can I replace just the rotten section or do I need a full new piece of wood? At any rate if I can work out the right terms I can research that.


I can't tell what that is from way back here. It could be wall sheathing, a header for the window, or floor framing. Please provide a clearer photo from up close. Move more junk out of the way.

Remove at least one section of siding from either side and all across the top of the window.
